# Can I install the latest version of KDE for my Red Hat 4.7 without privileges?

Tags: linux, redhat, kde, permissions

I just upgraded my linux machine to Red Hat 4.7 (we cannot use a newer version than this because the application we are using does not run on Red Hat 5).

I'm not the root so I cannot install any apps via rpm, and I cannot sudo either.

Is there a way to install the latest version of KDE, for example KDE 4.2, with these constraints?

Regards

Comment: Just wondering: *why* exactly do you want the latest version of KDE on that machine instead of the Red Hat supplied version? Have you though about the consequences of doing this?

Comment: Red Hat 4.7? Do you mean RHEL 4.7? That's different from Red Hat (Linux) 4.7.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you could download the source and install it in your home, and then you will have to change paths....

Answer (score 0):

@ Avery Payne :

Will need to add any pathing necessary to make sure that your private libraries load - you're not trying to install libraries to /usr/lib or/lib are you?

**Yes I can not write in those directories , so I have to install it under my home or work1.**

@ Avery Payne :

Know in advance how you want to install it into your home directory

**Yeah that is the question , so I want to now how can I do that ????**

Answer (score 0):

A convention for programs is to accept a `--prefix` flag to `./configure`, e.g.

```
./configure --prefix=/home/user/apps/kde
make
make install
```

Can't say that I've tried that with KDE though, don't know its build process.